# Expand block (emulating a paper page) vertically with CSS

Tags: css, html

I suspect this has alerady been asked, but I could not find a way to solve my problem with previous answers, or I didn't have the ability to do it (I started to study CSS ten days ago).

So I want to emulate a paper page similar to the ones shown in Adobe Reader or MS Word: a white shadow rectangle against a gray background. My requirement, though, is that, since I'm going to display it in a browser, I want to fit the page vertically, leaving a fixed-pixel-sized small margin on top and bottom.

So far, I have got the code below, which do not expand vertically. I have already got the page to look ok with maximized window using height:99%, but then the bottom margin keeps changing size, and I didn't like the effect. I want the bottom margin with fixed-sized pixel dimensions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <!-- TODO: Expand page vertically but leave fixed top and bottom margins -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Relatório Html</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            html {height: 100%}

            body {
                height: 100%;
                background-color: #ccc;
            }

            .paperpage {
                position: relative;
                width: 400px;
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
                margin-top:10px;
                margin-bottom:10px;
                padding:30px;
                background-color: white;
                box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="paperpage">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since it's a page, will it have pixel dimensions, or rather inches or centimeters?

Comment: @minitech Good question. Ideally I should have a "pdf-like" representation of an A4 page, with fonts and images and aspect-ratio with their relative sizes. Since the purpose of this page will be more like a general visualization, I don't mind using pixels and doing the conversion to milimeter in my head.

Comment: You should probably use `position: absolute` and `top: 10px; bottom: 10px` will stretch to full height with 5px difference.

Comment: @heltonbiker: Well, that's just the thing; you can't convert pixels to millimeters or vice-versa. What you *can* do, is specify them in your code :) That should eliminate most of your problems, just setting `width: 8.5in;` and `height: 11in;` or something similar (A4 size).

Comment: Wait... you want to have ALWAYS the paper FULLY visible, even at page resize?

Comment: @roXon : the idea seems doubtful even to me, but I learned, from designing GUI, that it is best to test your layout by resizing it, so that you can catch faulty reflows that are invisible when you use a fixed size. But I know this paper-page analogy is only partially valid, unfortunately.

Comment: @minitech : thanks for mentioning the `in` unit. I have not studied units yet, but I'll take a look, since all this paper-illusion thing is meant for judging the design possibilities of a printed report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `position: absolute;` and `top: 10px; bottom: 10px;`

Like in **[This Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MV7VR/)**

Comment: well, It worked! Only one thing: I would like the page to be centered in screen, but my previous centerint was gone. Any suggestion?

Comment: I figured you used a trick with negative margin and left, but it hardcoded three dependent numbers. Do you know a way to set just width and auto-center the page without other by-hand calculations and settings?

Comment: I'm afraid not without JavaScript, as `margin: auto` doesn't play well with `position: absolute`. You'll have to either calculate the numbers on the server side, or render it on the client's side with JavaScript (jQuery?)

Comment: Ok. If I discover some other magic I'll come back here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You also can do this dinamically:

```
<body>
    <div class="paperpage" id="paperpage">Try this</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    altura = window.document.height;

    document.getElementById('paperpage').style.height = (altura - 20) +"px";

</script>
```

Comment: Great. When I get to the "javascript" chapter, I'll take a look at your suggestion. Valeu.